# Get Time and Date of 'Like's on a Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Would there be any way to get the information about all the likes on a Facebook post of mine? For a statistics project, I need to get a list of all the people who 'like'd a post, and, more importantly, the time at which they liked it. Would this be possible at all, with Facebook Graph API or in any other way? I'd be very grateful for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the time the post was liked is unfortunately not being returned if you're using the

```
/{obect_id}/likes
```

endpoint. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/likes#read

Answer (score -1):

Read Action

```
GET /v2.2/me/og.likes HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

you can refer this here
 [OpenGraph facebook API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes)